# Invalid character in identifier.... How to solve it

Tags: python-3.x

```
File "<ipython-input-2-c2c2aa03b2a5>", line 25
librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr, x_axis=’time’, y_axis=’log’)
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifierputhon

import librosa

#path of the audio file

audio_data = read(NHS113.wav");

#This returns an audio time series as a numpy array with a default sampling rate(sr) of 22KHZ

x = librosa.load(audio_data, sr=None)

#We can change this behavior by resampling at sr=44.1KHz.

x = librosa.load(audio_data, sr=44000)

IPython.display.Audio(audio_data)


%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import librosa.display

plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))

#plotting the sampled signal

librosa.display.waveplot(x, sr=sr)

#x: numpy array

X = librosa.stft(x)

#converting into energy levels(dB)

Xdb = librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(X))

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))

librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr, x_axis='time', y_axis='hz')

plt.colorbar()

librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr, x_axis=’time’, y_axis=’log’)

librosa.feature.mfcc(x, sr=sr
```

Comment: You may also want to check `read(NHS113.wav")` – that's a bad literal string.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies with:

```
 librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr, x_axis=’time’, y_axis=’log’)
                                             ^    ^         ^   ^
                                              \________________/
```

Don't use smart quotes such as `’`, Python strings are formed with either `'` or `"`. Smart quotes often end up in your code by cutting and pasting from bad web pages, or using a word processor as a text editor.